# Kafka transaction commit timeout exception handling

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am running kafka transactions on a large scale and below is the codepiece.

```
producer.initTransaction();
try {
    producer.beginTransaction();
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(producerTopic, element));
    producer.commitTransaction();
} catch (ProducerFencedException | OutOfOrderSequenceException | AuthorizationException e) {
    producer.close();
    canSendNext = false;
}catch (KafkaException e) {
    producer.abortTransaction();
}
```

properties used:

> ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, STRING_SERIALIZER
> ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BYTE_ARRAY_SERIALIZER
> ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString()
> bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
> acks=all
> retries=1
> partitioner.class=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitioner

while the commitTransaction is timing out the catch block of KafkaException runs and try to abort the transaction.
Which fails with the error: **
Cannot attempt operation `abortTransaction` because the previous call to `commitTransaction` timed out and must be retried**

how to handle commit transaction timeout scenario

expecting the code to work

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#commitTransaction--):

> Note that this method will raise TimeoutException if the transaction
> cannot be committed before expiration of max.block.ms. Additionally,
> it will raise InterruptException if interrupted. It is safe to retry
> in either case, but it is not possible to attempt a different
> operation (such as abortTransaction) since the commit may already be
> in the progress of completing. If not retrying, the only option is to
> close the producer.

The problem here is that the kafka producer has timed out and it does not know whether the kafka broker will complete the transaction or not. So it cannot provide you abort transaction functionality as there is a chance that the transaction might have been committed by the broker even after the producer times out.

You should configure your kafka producer with a sufficiently large `max.block.ms` and good number of `retries` to handle such scenarios (Not sure why you have configured your retries to 1). Ideally you should be timing out very rarely - like when there is some issue in the network or there is some actual issue going on in kafka brokers.

In such scenarios, it won't be possible for you to know if your last transaction was actually successful or not. You cannot do anything but close your kafka producer and create a new one.